# Unity, PropertyDrawer.GetPropertyHeight doesn't get called in multiple arrays on element change

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've started rewriting my Curve tool to deal with problem of drawing it in array and other reasons. All was well till I tried to click between editors in array and list elements. Sometimes Previously edited element retains its height until other element of that collection gets edited or curve field gets edited. I have no idea how to tell Unity it should refresh field heights. I've tried `EditorUtility.SetDirty(targetObject);` with or without `EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();` `EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck();`

[image: example]

Number on left is OtherCurve.z, it's a way to deferenciate which PropertyDrawer you are debugging in code. Labels are temporal.

```
public class OtherTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public OtherCurve curve;
    public OtherCurve[] curveArray;
    public List<OtherCurve> curveList;
}
```

[Curve tool repository at last commit with the issue](https://github.com/zORg-alex/BezierZ/tree/c1b55fef30cc399148d435dc5a852b33076a394c)
To test download this commit code and put it in Assets/Plugins/ and add these to your Packages/manifest.json:

```
"st.one-line": "https://github.com/slavniyteo/one-line.git#master",
"st.rect-ex": "https://github.com/slavniyteo/rect-ex.git#master",
```

This code stays there, I'm not going to hide it from public or rewrite history of the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to recreate this behaviour on a simpler example I've found out that my technique works...

**Edited: Appears that using GUI.Label(..) to draw label in Editor and not using any other EditorGUI components caused GetPropertyHeight not being called.** So If I wouldn't stop at this bug, it would disappear when I replaced that GUI.Label placeholder with actually meaningful code. I feel empty for wasting that much time to figure this out.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
#endif

public class PropertyThing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CustomThing thing;
    public List<CustomThing> thingList;
    public CustomThing[] thingArray;

    [Serializable]
    public class CustomThing
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        public bool _isEdited;
#endif
        public string field;
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(CustomThing))]
    public class CustomThingInspector : PropertyDrawer
    {

        private UnityEngine.Object targetObject;
        private CustomThing value;
        private static Action FinishCurrentEditorAction;
        private static void FinishCurrentEditor() => FinishCurrentEditorAction();
        private static void FinishCurrentEditor(Scene s) => FinishCurrentEditorAction();

        private string EditButtonText(bool editing) => editing ? "Stop Edit" : "Edit";

        public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            GetObjects(property);
            return value._isEdited ? 38 : 18;
        }

        private void GetObjects(SerializedProperty property)
        {
            targetObject = property.serializedObject.targetObject;
            value = property.GetValue<CustomThing>();
        }

        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            var c = GUI.color;
            GetObjects(property);
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

            var firstline = new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, 18);
            var editor = new Rect(position.x, position.y + 20, position.width, position.height - 20);

            var brect = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(firstline, label);
            if (value._isEdited) GUI.color = Color.red * .6666f + Color.white * .3333f;
            if (GUI.Button(brect, EditButtonText(value._isEdited)))
            {
                EditPressed();
            }
            GUI.color = c;

            if (value._isEdited)
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(editor, property.FindPropertyRelative("field"));

            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
            GUI.color = c;
        }

        private void EditPressed()
        {
            value._isEdited = !value._isEdited;
            if (value._isEdited)
                StartEditor(value);
            else
                FinishEditor(value);
        }

        private void StartEditor(CustomThing thing)
        {
            var capturedThing = thing;
            FinishCurrentEditorAction?.Invoke();
            FinishCurrentEditorAction = () => {
                FinishEditor(capturedThing);
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(targetObject);
                FinishCurrentEditorAction = null;
            };
            capturedThing._isEdited = true;
            SceneView.duringSceneGui += OnEditorSceneView;
        }

        private void FinishEditor(CustomThing thing)
        {
            Selection.selectionChanged -= FinishCurrentEditor;
            EditorSceneManager.sceneClosed -= FinishCurrentEditor;
            AssemblyReloadEvents.beforeAssemblyReload -= FinishCurrentEditor;
            SceneView.duringSceneGui -= OnEditorSceneView;
            thing._isEdited = false;
            FinishCurrentEditorAction = null;
        }

        private void OnEditorSceneView(SceneView obj)
        {
            if (targetObject is Component c)
                Handles.Label(c.transform.position, c.gameObject.name);
            else
                Handles.Label(Vector3.zero, targetObject.name);
        }
    }


#endif
}

public static class SerializedUtility
{

    public static T GetValue<T>(this SerializedProperty property) where T : class
    {
        object obj = property.serializedObject.targetObject;
        string path = property.propertyPath.Replace(".Array.data", "");
        string[] fieldStructure = path.Split('.');
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\[\d+\]");
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldStructure.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fieldStructure[i].Contains("["))
            {
                int index = System.Convert.ToInt32(new string(fieldStructure[i].Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()));
                obj = GetFieldValueWithIndex(rgx.Replace(fieldStructure[i], ""), obj, index);
            }
            else
            {
                obj = GetFieldValue(fieldStructure[i], obj);
            }
        }
        return (T)obj;
    }

    public static bool SetValue<T>(this SerializedProperty property, T value) where T : class
    {
        object obj = property.serializedObject.targetObject;
        string path = property.propertyPath.Replace(".Array.data", "");
        string[] fieldStructure = path.Split('.');
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\[\d+\]");
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldStructure.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (fieldStructure[i].Contains("["))
            {
                int index = System.Convert.ToInt32(new string(fieldStructure[i].Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()));
                obj = GetFieldValueWithIndex(rgx.Replace(fieldStructure[i], ""), obj, index);
            }
            else
            {
                obj = GetFieldValue(fieldStructure[i], obj);
            }
        }

        string fieldName = fieldStructure.Last();
        if (fieldName.Contains("["))
        {
            int index = System.Convert.ToInt32(new string(fieldName.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()));
            return SetFieldValueWithIndex(rgx.Replace(fieldName, ""), obj, index, value);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(value);
            return SetFieldValue(fieldName, obj, value);
        }
    }

    private static object GetFieldValue(string fieldName, object obj, BindingFlags bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    {
        FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, bindings);
        if (field != null)
        {
            return field.GetValue(obj);
        }
        return default(object);
    }

    private static object GetFieldValueWithIndex(string fieldName, object obj, int index, BindingFlags bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    {
        FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, bindings);
        if (field != null)
        {
            object list = field.GetValue(obj);
            if (list.GetType().IsArray)
            {
                return ((object[])list)[index];
            }
            else if (list is IEnumerable)
            {
                return ((IList)list)[index];
            }
        }
        return default(object);
    }

    public static bool SetFieldValue(string fieldName, object obj, object value, bool includeAllBases = false, BindingFlags bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    {
        FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, bindings);
        if (field != null)
        {
            field.SetValue(obj, value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool SetFieldValueWithIndex(string fieldName, object obj, int index, object value, bool includeAllBases = false, BindingFlags bindings = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    {
        FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, bindings);
        if (field != null)
        {
            object list = field.GetValue(obj);
            if (list.GetType().IsArray)
            {
                ((object[])list)[index] = value;
                return true;
            }
            else if (value is IEnumerable)
            {
                ((IList)list)[index] = value;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this code will help somebody. Didn't see any feedback here.

Comment: So... I'm speechless...
Changed this: 
 private void DrawEditor(Rect position)
 {
  GUI.Label(position, $"I'm in Editor");
 }
To this

 private void DrawEditor(Rect position)
 {
  EditorGUI.LabelField(position, $"I'm in Editor");
 }
And it made all the difference. WTF?
I wasn't even looking at this line. And it was ruining my property drawer height updates all this time? I've lost so many hours on this ***t.